# Docker MongoDB Cluster/ReplicaSet with a base database and collection

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am a Docker novice and have been trying for a long time, but I still cannot create the containers as expected.

This is my current configuration, but it does not meet the expectations: `MongoServerError: no replset config has been received`

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  RoteMongoFirst:
    image: mongo:5
    command: mongod --replSet roteReplicaSet --bind_ip localhost,RoteMongoFirst 
    container_name: RoteMongoFirst
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=Rote
      - MONGO_REPLICA_SET_MODE=primary
    volumes:
      - ./mongodb/RoteMongoFirst:/data/db
      - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

    networks:
      - rote-network

  RoteMongoSecond:
    image: mongo:5
    depends_on:
      - RoteMongoFirst
    command: >
      bash -c "mongod --replSet roteReplicaSet --bind_ip localhost,RoteMongoSecond &&
      mongosh --eval \"rs.initiate({ _id: \\"roteReplicaSet\\", members: [ { _id: 0, host: \\"RoteMongoFirst\\" }, { _id: 1, host: \\"RoteMongoSecond\\" } ]})\""
    container_name: RoteMongoSecond
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=Rote
      - MONGO_REPLICA_SET_MODE=secondary
    volumes:
      - ./mongodb/RoteMongoSecond:/data/db
      - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - rote-network

networks:
  rote-network:
```

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple entries in `--bind_ip` often causes trouble. I would suggest to use either `--bind_ip localhost` or `--bind_ip_all`. Using `--bind_ip` with an IP makes only sense if your computer has multiple network interfaces. However,  MongoDB does not support multiple network interfaces, so still it does not make much sense.

Regarding you actual problem: You need to wait a bit till ReplicaSet is initiated. Try to add

```
while (! db.hello().isWritablePrimary ) sleep(1000)
```

after your `rs.initiate(..)` command.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a long time, I finally wrote a docker-compose file that meets expectations. It implements the creation of a MongoDB cluster and initializes a database (Rote) containing a collection (Rote). I hope it can help some people.

> otherwise,Claude is really useful than gpt3.5

```
version: "3"

services:
  mongors1:
    image: mongo:7
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    entrypoint: ["/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "rs0"]

  mongors2:
    image: mongo:7
    restart: always
    entrypoint: ["/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "rs0"]

  mongo-setup:
    image: mongo:4
    restart: on-failure
    entrypoint:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - |
        mongo --host mongors1:27017 --eval 'rs.initiate({
          _id: "rs0",
          members: [
            {_id: 0, host: "mongors1:27017", priority: 2},
            {_id: 1, host: "mongors2:27017", priority: 1}
          ]
        })' && mongo --host mongors1:27017 --eval 'while (! db.hello().isWritablePrimary ) sleep(1000); db = db.getSiblingDB("Rote"); db.createCollection("Rote");'
    depends_on:
      - mongors1
      - mongors2
```