# MongoDB Shard Cluster

Tags: mongodb, sharding

Good day people .Am having some trouble adding initiating replicas using the rs.initiate().
below is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  configs1:
    container_name: configs1
    image: mongo:6.0-focal
    command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - |
        mongod --keyFile /data/keyFile --configsvr --replSet cfgrs --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db
    ports:
      - 10001:27017
    volumes:
      - ./keyFile:/data/keyFile
      - configs1:/data/db
    
  configs2:
    container_name: configs2
    image: mongo:6.0-focal
    command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - |
        mongod --keyFile /data/keyFile --configsvr --replSet cfgrs --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db
    ports:
      - 10002:27017
    volumes:
      - ./keyFile:/data/keyFile
      - configs2:/data/db
    

  configs3:
    container_name: configs3
    image: mongo:6.0-focal
    command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - |
        mongod --keyFile /data/keyFile --configsvr --replSet cfgrs --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db  
    ports:
      - 10003:27017
    volumes:
      - ./keyFile:/data/keyFile
      - configs3:/data/db
   

volumes:
  configs1:
  configs2:
  configs3:
```

But when I try to access the docker container interactively and the use mongosh to access the DB. When I try

```
rs.initiate(
  {
    _id: "cfgrs",
    configsvr: true,
    members: [
      { _id : 0, host : "my-ip-address:10001" },
      { _id : 0, host : "my-ip-address:10002" },
    ]
  }
);
```

I get the following error MongoServerError: No host described in new configuration with {version: 1, term: 0} for replica set cfgrs maps to this node what could be the problem. Any help will be highly appreciated

I have tried using my docker ip address but it still bring that error.

Comment: Maybe this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78118861/docker-mongodb-cluster-replicaset-with-a-base-database-and-collection/78120063?noredirect=1#comment137724848_78120063

Comment: You provided a keyfile `--keyFile`, however I think without authentication enabled, it does not take effect. When you enable authentication then you must also create an admin user.

Comment: I cannot even create a user I get this error MongoServerError: not primary

Comment: How do you connect? Try to add `readPreference=primaryPreferred` to connection string

Comment: i figured out that i need to add the bind_ip_all to connect but however on my first login i can't even run rs.initiate(). i keep geeting this error MongoServerError: command createUser requires authentication

Comment: That means, the admin user is created already. You must connect with credentials.

Comment: but when i try to use docker exec -it configs1 bash then  mongosh --host localhost:27017 -u username -p "" --authenticationDatabase admin. still bring authentication failed. I tried adding MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME and MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD to the evironment section of my docker-compose file.

Comment: Honestly I have no clue about docker, I follow the [Deploy Sharded Cluster with Keyfile Authentication](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/deploy-sharded-cluster-with-keyfile-access-control/). Certainly another problem is you add two member with `_id: 0`, that will fail. The `_id`'s must be distinct.

Comment: Thank you for time and input i finally got away. I had to first start the container with out auth then after use auth.